# Looking for a live feed of tides in Australia

Tags: data, weather, australia

I'm looking for a feed of predicted tide heights and times, specifically for NSW, Australia.

Tide sites such as the [Bureau of Meteorology](http://www.bom.gov.au/oceanography/tides/MAPS/nsw.shtml) only provide static images of predicted tide height. NSW Maritime publish a calendar of tide heights in [PDF format](http://www.maritime.nsw.gov.au/docs/Tide_Tables.pdf).

Ideally I'd like to display a dynamic chart for a series of locations along the coast, in a similar manner to the tide chart on [this site](http://tides.willyweather.com.au/nsw/greater-western-sydney/georges-river--warwick-farm.html).

Does anyone know where I can get a feed of the raw numbers for the coming week?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get tabular (in HTML format) tide predictions from BOM.  Maybe an HTML scraper like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) could parse it for you.

An example of accessing the tabular tide predictions for Botany Bay:http://www.bom.gov.au/cgi-bin/oceanography/tides/tide_predications.cgi?location=nsw_60390&tide_hiddenField=New%20South%20Wales&years=2012&months=Feb&dates=14

Station codes:

```
  Botany Bay  nsw_60390
  Eden  nsw_60530
  Lord Howe Island  nsw_57720
  Newcastle nsw_60310
  Norfolk Island  nsw_57700
  Port Kembla  nsw_60420
  Sydney (Fort Denison) nsw_60370
  Yamba  nsw_60130
```

Comment: Thanks! Where did you get the station codes, and are they available for other stations along the coast? The "other locations" link leads to MHL but doesn't seem to show the station codes

Comment: It was as simple as Right click->View source on the NSW link you posted in your question.  It only shows stations that are in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 2):

Could also try the Navy Meteorology site

http://www.metoc.gov.au/products.php

They have a ton of marine data